# C++ exception list is ignored

Tags: c++, exception

I've been learning C++ and now I'm in the topic of exception handling. The book says that anything other than the exceptions in the exception list are prevented from leaving the function, so I tested it and expected the program to terminate due to uncaught exception. Now the thing is, the exception list is ignored, how do I deal with this?

```
int diva(int a, int b) 
throw(int, runtime_error)
{
    if (b == 0)
        throw invalid_argument("div by 0");

    return a/b ;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    set_terminate(errnote);
    try {
        diva(4,0);
    } catch(const invalid_argument& e) {
        cout<<e.what()<<endl;
    }

}
```

The program still executes and the exception is still caught.

I also get the warning:

> Warning   1   warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to
>   indicate a function is not
>   __declspec(nothrow)   c:\users\siegfred\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\procpp\procpp\maindriver.cpp    20  1   ProCpp

Comment: Exception specifications are deprecated, and it is only recommended to use `throw()` pre C++11 and `noexcept` beginning with C++11. Both `throw()` and `noexcept` mean basically the same thing: I promise I don't throw anything, and I won't allow any exceptions to escape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa28fef8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

visual C++ does not implement exception specification of function.

your `throw( int, runetime_error )` is simply ignored by the compiler and has no effect.